# Fitting a door to an unusual frame size?

Tags: doors, door-frame, security, joinery

I’ve inherited this front door that’s seen better days.
[image: Old door]

I’m hoping to replace it with a nice, new, off-the-shelf door (hardwood veneer, solid core).

However, the door frame measures 2080 x 915mm and the closest door sizes I can find off-the-shelf are:

- 1981 x 915mm
- 2134 x 915mm

As you can see in this image, the current frame lacks a sill:
[image: The door frame lacks a sill]

The frame itself seems to be in good condition, so I don’t want to remove that.

What’s the best approach? Build up a sill to make the smaller door fit? Or try and trim down the larger door?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The door frame does look like it can use some work, but the door is nice looking.  Have you thought about refinishing the door?  Modern doors unless quite expensive are usually quite cheaply made.  Solid doors can usually be cut down to size if needed, other doors might only have a limited amount of cut down available.

Comment: Your real problem may be uninsulated glass, but the door looks quite nice to me—I'd be trying to repair the frame and the transom window (maybe replace with an IGU) and keep the door.